# valgrind not building 32 bit rpm on 64 bit machine

Tags: valgrind

I have 32 bit C application(running on 64 bit system) leaking memory.

Do debug it I have downloaded valgrind 3.8.1 from http://valgrind.org/downloads/.
Did ./configure, make and make install to install valgrind.

But valgrind builds only 64 bit memcheck-amd64-linux binary.
32 bit memcheck is not getting built.

As a result I get below errors

```
# valgrind --tool=memcheck --time-stamp=yes -v --track-origins=yes --leak-check=yes /home/test_code32 --error-limit=no
valgrind: failed to start tool 'memcheck' for platform 'x86-linux': No such file or directory
```

Stracing valgrind gives me:

```
execve("/usr/local/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux", ["valgrind", "--tool=memcheck", "--time-stamp=yes", "-v", "--track-origins=yes", "--leak-check=yes", "/home/test_code32", "--error-limit=no"], [/* 60 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "valgrind: failed to start tool '"..., 94valgrind: failed to start tool 'memcheck' for platform 'x86-linux': No such file or directory
) = 94
```

I checked the ./configure output and it says:

```
checking for 32 bit build support... no
```

I am using gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.3.4.

Any idea how to get valgrind build 32 bit memcheck on 64 bit machine?

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue.
I installed 32-bit gcc support and then again built valgrind and it created the 32 bit memcheck.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and resolved it by setting an environment variable:

```
export VALGRIND_LIB=/YourValgrindInstallDirectory/lib/valgrind
```

which is the direcory where valgrind missing lib is.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-running your `configure` script with the `--enable-only32bit` option:

```
 ./configure --enable-only32bit
```

Comment: Thanks troydj for the reply.
I had tried all those things but were of no help.

Comment: where do I find that script ? I have installed it with dnf

Answer (score 0):

I installed the 32bit version of valgrind and it seems that it works now. The information about installing the 32bit version I took it from [here](http://valgrind.10908.n7.nabble.com/32-bit-process-on-64-bit-machine-suspicion-for-failed-to-start-memcheck-td40421.html)