# Valgrind analysis in 32-bit elf file on 64-bit Linux Docker machine

Tags: linux, gitlab, valgrind, esp8266, docker-image

I would like to use **Valgrind** tool for **ESP8266** code & memory analysis.

I am trying to use it in **Gitlab's job**, the .elf file is **32-bits** and is compiled in another job using **platformio**, ok with that.

In the Valgrind job, I am trying to use different **docker images** (which all are **64-bits**), but I see similar errors when running Valgrind. I have been facing architecture issues because the .elf file is 32-bits and the image 64-bits, and then I am facing and issue with **memcheck**.

The commands running in the job are these ones:

- uname --machine

  `x86_64`
- apt-get update && apt-get install -y valgrind valgrind-dbg g++ libc6-dbg

  Installation is OK.
- dpkg-query -L valgrind

  Many directories are shown:
  `/usr/bin/valgrind /usr/include/valgrind /usr/lib/valgrind /usr/share/doc/valgrind (...)`
- export VALGRIND_LIB="/usr/lib/valgrind/"
- export CFLAGS=-m32
- file firmware.elf

  `firmware.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Tensilica Xtensa, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped`
- linux32 --32bit valgrind --force-arch=i386 --leak-check=full ./firmware.elf

  I have run this command with & without `linux32` `--32bit` `--force-arch=i386`

  When running the last command, I see 3 different errors depending on the docker image I am using:

1. image: **vowstar/esp8266**.
   `valgrind: wrong ELF executable class (eg. 32-bit instead of 64-bit) valgrind: ./firmware.elf: cannot execute binary file`
2. image: **i386/ubuntu**.
   `valgrind: executable is not for this architecture valgrind: ./firmware.elf: cannot execute binary file`
3. image: **espressif/idf**.
   `valgrind: failed to start tool 'memcheck' for platform 'amd64-linux': No such file or directory`

Seems like the third image goes further, but I am unable to install memcheck.

Any easier way to use Valgrind in a docker image?

I know there are some similar questions about this, but nothing worked for me:

[valgrind not building 32 bit rpm on 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635735/valgrind-not-building-32-bit-rpm-on-64-bit-machine)

[Ubuntu: valgrind: failed to start tool 'memcheck' for platform 'amd64-linux': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813183/ubuntu-valgrind-failed-to-start-tool-memcheck-for-platform-amd64-linux-no)

[How to compile a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit linux machine with gcc/cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272357/how-to-compile-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine-with-gcc-cmake)

Comment: `Valgrind tool for ESP8266` What _linux_ and dynamic loader are you running on ESP8266? Does ESP8266 is capable of having virtual addresses at all? Do not understand how valgrind works? Why aren't you compiling _and running_ valgrind __on__ ESP8266?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESP8266 has no MMU capable of virtual memory, so it's not possible to run dynamic linker on it, so it's not possible to run valgrind *on* ESP8266.